# Error message box select statement to handle yes or no

Tags: vba, excel

need help with the yes no portion of the error message, if yes I want the code to be launched again and if no then exit sub.

```
Public Sub Reset()
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim slice As Slicer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh

    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        pt.RefreshTable
        For Each slice In pt.Slicers
           slice.SlicerCache.ClearAllFilters
On Error GoTo 0
    Next slice
        pt.PivotCache.Refresh
    Next pt
Error 0:
    MsgBox "Sorry, Missing data, do you wish to continue?", _
                vbCritical vbYesNo, "Restart process!"
            Select Case vbYesNo
                Case yes
                    MergeMultipleSheets
                Case Else
                Exit Sub
            End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is yes no portion of your code (assuming that you want to launch module MergeMultipleSheets if yes button is clicked):

```
Sub Reset()
    Dim xlAns As Integer

    xlAns = MsgBox("Sorry, Missing data, do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "Restart process!")
    Select Case xlAns
    Case vbYes
'        do something
'        if You want to call sub MergeMultipleSheets
        MergeMultipleSheets
    Case Else
'        do something
        Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistances

Answer (score 0):

Quick Example

```
Sub MsgBx()
    Dim xlMsgBox As Integer
    Dim Cancel As Boolean

    xlMsgBox = MsgBox("Do you want to do this ", vbYesNoCancel)

    If xlMsgBox = vbCancel Then
        Cancel = True ' Exit
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf xlMsgBox = vbYes Then
'          do something
    ElseIf xlMsgBox = vbNo Then
'          do something
    End If

End Sub
```